# Get Gravity from Android Accelerometer

Tags: android, filter, accelerometer, sensors

I'm working with the Accelerometer Sensor from my Android, but I have a problem.

I need to get only gravity and i don't know how to do.

I read in the official documentation of Android the following method:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
 {
      // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
      // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
      // and dT, the event delivery rate

      final float alpha = 0.8;

      gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
      gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
      gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

      linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
      linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
      linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
 }
```

So I guess would be good if I take the gravity[] values.

I'm I right?

Sensor is: BMA250 3 axis accelerometer, documentation is in:
[BMA250](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/783/BST-BMA250-DS002-05-786487.pdf)

Comment: I'm still stuck in this :(

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473819/removing-gravity-from-accelerometer-documentation-code) if that still helps.